# Loading images and adding to Stage in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to load an image object and add it to the stage at runtime. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 3):

if it's an external image you would use this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://urltoyourimage.jpg"));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);

function onCompleteHandler(event:Event):void 
{
  event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
  addChild(event.target.content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a Loader.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html

There's a code example near the bottom.